# Generating all strings that a regular expressions describe

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I'm having trouble generating the set of strings, which a regular expressions describe.
A typical regular expression can look like this:

```
[atom_0] atom_1 (atom_2 | atorm_3 | ... | atom_n-1) <var> [atom_n]
```

Or any other combination of the following:

```
[], means, that the atom inside of it can be omitted
(), one of the atoms (seperated by | (stands for OR)) inside the braces can be chosen 
<>, variable.
atom, it can be thought as a constant, which is hard coded.
```

For example:

```
The [yellow] (dog | cat) named <animalName>
```

This expression describes the following set of strings:

```
The yellow dog named <animalName>;
The yellow cat named <animalName>;
The dog named <animalName>;
The cat named <animal Name>;
```

The strings can vary, depending on the variable `<animalName>`, but say, we have two names for `<variableName>` : `Petsy` and `Rony`, then w'll have:

```
The yellow dog named Petsy;
The yellow cat named Petsy;
The dog named Petsy;
The cat named Petsy;
The yellow dog named Rony;
The yellow cat named Rony;
The dog named Rony;
The cat named Rony;
```

Right now, I'm thinking that I could build a tree (or graph) from the expression and then a DFS or BFS can do the job.

Any comments or document/article references would be helpful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard construction for converting regular expressions into finite automata (check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction_algorithm) or any textbook on formal languages). Once you have such an automaton in hand (either NFA or DFA) you can enumerate all accepted strings with a breadth-first search from the initial state looking for finite states (ordered by length).

Be careful, though: in general, regular expressions specify infinite languages. You can easily specify a length limit, though.

Comment: Thank you, @Raphael. It seems that an automatan representation of the grammar will suit my goals.

Answer (score 1):

For regular expressions specified the way you describe, you can use a backtracking algorithm to enumerate all acceptable strings. Following is a Python implementation.

The input is a list of items. An item being one of the ones you describe.

`gen_candidates` generates candidates for the k'th position.

```
def gen_candidates(item):
    c = []
    if type(item) is list:
        for e in item: c.append(e)
        if(len(item) == 1):
            c.append('')
    elif type(item) is str:
        c.append(item)
    return c
```

The next function prints a solution when one is found.

```
def process_solution(solution):
    s = ''
    for e in solution:
        if len(e) > 0:
            s += e + ' '
    print(s)
```

`backtrack` tries all possibilities recursively.

```
def backtrack(regex, solution, k):
    if len(regex) > 0:
        candidates = gen_candidates(regex[0])
        for c in candidates:
            solution[k] = c
            backtrack(regex[1:], solution, k + 1)
    else:
        process_solution(solution)
```

You invoke the algorithm as follows:

```
input = ['The', ['yellow'], ['dog', 'cat'], 'named', '<animalName>']
solution = ['', '', '', '', '']
backtrack(input, solution, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer @saadtaame. I did some digging and I found that this kind grammar is called `speech recognition` grammar, however it turns out that there is a nice way to represent it in xml format. Further, I don't know python very well, but it seems to me, that you tread the constructions `[atom1 | atom2 | ... | atomN]` and `(atom1 | atom2 | ... | atomN)` as equally like and this is not suitable for me. Thank you again, for your answer and the time you spent on it ( :